# How to see all changes made by an admin

Tags: 7, users, log-messages

Is it possible to somehow pull a report on an admins activity on a Drupal 7 site? I'd like to know for example any development changes, and settings changes, and database changes that an admin on a site has performed.

I've found some modules that help with that, but its too late to install them now.

Comment: You can view a simple list of sessions and page edits using the system log at admin/reports/dblog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Administration Notifications](https://drupal.org/project/administration_notification) this is a simple module that can be used for communication of site changes/updates between the site designer/developer, and the site owners.

> if you maintain a drupal installation for another company, you can use
>   this module to inform them when you have updated versions of the site
>   (ex drupal 7.1 -> 7.2), updated modules on the site (i.e.
>   Administration Notifications 7.x-1.0 -> 7.x-1.1), added new modules,
>   or changed the site design in some manner.

or you can try [Activity](https://drupal.org/project/activity) module.

> The Activity module keeps track of the things people do on your site
>   and provides mini-feeds of these activities in blocks, in a
>   specialized table, and via RSS. The module is extensible so that any
>   other module can integrate with it. The messages that are produced are
>   customizable via the admin interface and are context sensitive.

[image]

Comment: Beware: activity is practically abandoned.